# How to do validation for NUMBERS only in PHP?

Tags: php, validation, numbers

How do I do some sort of validation that will only accept numbers since I have an Age input type?

```
$age = $_POST['age'];




<input type="text" class="form-control" name="age" placeholder="Age">
```

Comment: You could use input type "number" for a start.

Comment: `(int)`, `intval`, `filter_var`, `ctype_digit` whatever

Comment: too many ways to do this; what did you try?

Comment: thanks for the ideas sirs/madams!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`type casting`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) for this purpose:

```
$age = (int)$_POST['age'];
```

In case the value isn't a number, it would be converted to one.

After that you should check `if($age > 0)` since a value which isn't a number probably would be converted to 0 (zero).

Furthermore, since it's an age value - you can also check for a range.
Just for "convenience" validation.

**A note regarding @AmanKumar & @OllyBarca answer/comment**

While setting an input `type="number"` would force the user to enter a number. Any one with a little knowledge can bypass this one and send data directly to the server side. That's why you should NOT rely on client-side validation rules.

Comment: typecasting is NOT validation! Use "is_numeric" or "ctype_digit" to do an actual check

Comment: typecasting is just the first part of the answer. The validation's part is the "if($age >0)" part.

Comment: In case my answer helped you please consider approving it.

Answer (score 2):

### Simply you should change HTML input type

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="age" placeholder="Age">

if(isset($_POST['age']) && is_numeric($_POST['age']))
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (is_int($_POST['age']) && $_POST['age'] > 0)` should do the trick

Comment: What if age is `12300922`?

Comment: Sorry, but "is_int" will always return false for POST values (because anything from POST will be of type string)... you will want "is_numeric"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quikest and easy to understand easy to implement solution

```
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
  return $data;
}

  
    if (empty($_POST['csphno'])) {
    $errormsg = "Lab Phone is required";
  } else {
      if (is_numeric($_POST['csphno'])) {
          
       $csphno = test_input($_POST['csphno']);
        
       if(strlen($csphno) < 9){
              $errormsg = "Lab Phone can not be less than 9 digits Please Enter Correct number";
          }
      } else {
        $errormsg = 'Error: Please enter only numbers in Lab Phone field.';
        }
      
}
```